How many Bluetooth/BLE devices can pair with one iPad?
Is there a limit to how many Bluetooth/BLE devices can be paired with one iPad? What is the limit?
I’m aware there is a limit of 7 active connections in BLE 5.0. I’m curious if there is a limit to the pairing in iOS/iPadOS.

Is there a specific problem, or are you just curious who has the most records in their database of connections?

You can normally connect around 7 devices at once. However it does depend on the type of device and bandwidth requirements. So for instance you cannot use two keyboards and two mice at once, only one keyboard and mouse is supported at a time. Headphones are the same except for Audio Sharing which will give the option for two of the same device. Really there’s no limit until it runs out of bandwidth to support the devices.  I hope this helps.

Welcome to Ask Different. I’m not sure a database of pairing that the iOS stores  uses any bandwidth. Are you reading the OP asking about paired devices to mean they want to connect to all of them at the same instant?

That’s the way I took it.  I honestly am not sure if they were referring specifically to the database of connections so I assumed it was more on instant usage.

I intended the pairing specifically and not the connections but that is still useful information. I’ll update the question to be more specific
